# Selecting Entity attribute of type enumarated collection via HQL (Hibernate)

Tags: hibernate, hql

we are using java+hibernate setup, my entity (and enum) looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(indexes = {@javax.persistence.Index(columnList = "sendDate", name = "foo_bar_idx"),...})
@EntityDomain(EntityType.Message)
public class Message extends AuditedClass {

    /**
     * The Types.
     */
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @ElementCollection
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    List<MessageType> types;


    @JsonSerialize(using = LocalDateTimeSerializer.class)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateTimeDeserializer.class)
    @Type(type = "org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime")
    LocalDateTime sendDate;

    //more attributes
    ...
    //getters and setters
    ...
}

public enum MessageType{
    VALUE_1,
    VALUE_2;
}
```

I am trying to `getCurrentSession().createQuery(queryString);` following `queryString`:

```
select m.sendDate, m.types from Message m
```

but i am getting an error:

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: not an entity [select m.sendDate, m.types from mydomain.message.Message m]
```

What am I doing wrong? Any other ideas? Hibernate 5.0.11

Update:

As requested here is essence of the code around query:

```
//imports
...
@Component("messageService")
@Transactional
public class MessageServiceImpl extends GenericHibernateServiceImpl implements MessageService {
    //@Autewired services
    ...
    //    other methods
    ...

    @Override
    public List<Foo> getFoos(/*inconsequential arguments*/) {

        List<Foo> list = new Vector<Foo>();
        try {
            Query query = getCurrentSession().createQuery("select m.sendDate, m.types from Message m");
            //execution does not reach here, error is thrown on the row above
        }
        catch (Throwable t) {
            //log and stuff
        }

        return list;
    }

    //    more methods
    ...
}
```

It is part of the method ment to be autowired and used by spring controllers.

Update 2 - stacktrace as requested:

```
Exception: not an entity [select m.sendDate, m.types from cz.trask.edoceo.domain.message.Message m]. StackTrace: org.hibernate.QueryException: not an entity [select m.sendDate, m.types from cz.trask.edoceo.domain.message.Message m]
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.generateQueryException(QueryException.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.QueryException.wrapWithQueryString(QueryException.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:302)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:240)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1894)
    at cz.trask.edoceo.service.impl.MessageServiceImpl.getFoos(MessageServiceImpl.java:388)
    //over 100 traces
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.executeProduceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceConsume(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:671)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:589)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: not an entity
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElementType.renderIdentifierSelect(FromElementType.java:174)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromElement.renderIdentifierSelect(FromElement.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SelectClause.renderNonScalarIdentifiers(SelectClause.java:465)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SelectClause.renderNonScalarSelects(SelectClause.java:421)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SelectClause.initializeExplicitSelectClause(SelectClause.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.useSelectClause(HqlSqlWalker.java:920)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processQuery(HqlSqlWalker.java:688)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:673)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:257)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:262)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:190)
    ... 122 more
, user=sysadmin, entityType=null, entityId=null
```

Comment: did you declare `<mapping class="your.full.package.path.Message" />` at your main hibernate xml file?

Comment: No. We are using minimalistic .xml file while managing everything through code annotations (so far we handled every problem this way). I am not inclined to breaking convention - is it necessary to edit config?

Comment: Can you show the entire code around `getCurrentSession().createQuery(queryString);`?

Comment: @Dherik question updated to include requested code

Comment: @user2522115 what the content of the `Foo` class? You need a `Foo` class with two parameters on the Foo constructor to receive the `m.sendDate, m.types`. Like: `select new com.package.Foo(m.sendDate, m.types) from Message m`. You can also use a Object array, like: `List<Object[]> list = new Vector<Object[]>();` and mantain the same jpql. Try and tell me what happenned

Comment: @Dherik I am afraid we are quite not understanding each other - the execution failes before conversion into desired `Foo` class instances. 

BTW The conversion is done by:
    `Foo foo;
    for (Object[] row : result) {
        foo = new Foo();
        foo.setBar((Bar) row[567]);
        //multiple attributes
        list.add(foo);
    }`

Comment: @user2522115, the conversion is made by the framework when you create a JPQL that returns m.sendDate, m.types (Object array) but you expect a Foo class. The error is saying that to you: `not an entity [select m.sendDate, m.types from mydomain.message.Message m]`.  Maybe you can share the full stacktrace error to us.

Comment: @Dherik stack trace added. I know that the problematic atribute is m.types (without selecting that column querry executes succesfully) which is enum, so indeed not an entity, however with those anotations as far as i know it should work.

Comment: @user2522115, what annotations exactly?

Comment: @Dherik     
    /**
     * The Types.
     */
    \@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    \@ElementCollection
    \@Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL)
    List<MessageType> types;

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the query to join messages with types:

```
select m.sendDate, t from Message m join m.types t
```